# Tortoise SVN, find all non-added files?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I am using Tortoise SVN on Windows.

I have a deep directory structure (using cakephp).

After creating several files I then went through and `+add`ed them.

The new files show a `?` next to them and a `+` next to them after set to add so it is easy to tell which files still need to be added. this is the same with folders.

However if a new file is inside an old folder there will still be the green checkmark. You won't have any indicator telling you there is a new file.

So I forgot to add one before a commit. This wouldn't be so bad as I could just add it and recommit. However, I also made this a tag, so I had recommit to the tag and the trunk.

Anyways this wouldn't have been an issue if there was an indicator on existing folders that contain new files.

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings->Icon Overlays->Show overlay for unversioned item

Comment: Actually what I needed to check was "Unversioned files mark parent folder as modified .. But you led me to the right place.

Comment: you're right indeed, forgot to check the exact explanation of all options.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Check-for-modifications dialog, then enable the checkbox "show unversioned items". It will show you all unversioned items that are not ignored. You can then add them directly from that dialog.